# What is the gradle configuration for jetpack compose with viewmodel and livedata?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.exercisecompose'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exercisecompose"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.5.3"
}
```

where `compose_ui_version` is `1.1.1`.  If I try to build the app I see an error complaining about duplicate collections classes amongst stdlib versions presumably packages as part of imported libraries.  I'm assuming it's from versions that are incompatible with one another in build.gradle but how do I find the out of date libraries?

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class
> kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules
> kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and
> kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21
> (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewmodel: TimerViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ExerciseComposeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    //Greeting("Android")
                    // Row 1 is a textview displaying time
                    // Row 2 consists of 3 buttons equally spaced
                    Row(
                        // Modifier.fillMaxSize() is usually passed into a Composable
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            viewmodel.timer.observeAsState().value?.time.toString()
                        )
                    }
                    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        Button(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 24.dp),
                            onClick = {
                                viewmodel.startTimer()
                            }
                        ) {
                            Text("Start")
                        }

                        Button(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 24.dp),
                            onClick = {
                                viewmodel.pauseTimer()
                            }
                        ) {
                            Text("Pause")
                        }

                        Button(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 24.dp),
                            onClick = {
                                viewmodel.stopTimer()
                            }
                        ) {
                            Text("Stop")
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get rid of such problems is to use Compose BOM.

[BOM Version Mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping?hl=en)

> The Compose Bill of Materials (BOM) lets you manage all of your
> Compose library versions by specifying only the BOM’s version. The BOM
> itself has links to the stable versions of the different Compose
> libraries, in such a way that they work well together. When using the
> BOM in your app, you don't need to add any version to the Compose
> library dependencies themselves. When you update the BOM version, all
> the libraries that you're using are automatically updated to their new
> versions.

This is how you can find incompatibility issues.